# How do I handle complicated algebraic manipulations?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have some complicated expressions which are defined below:

```
A[z_]:=(Sqrt[(2/a)*Sqrt[2]*(2*b^2-Λ^2)(Sqrt[2]*b+Λ)]*Cosh[Sqrt[2*b^2-Λ^2]*z])/(Sqrt[2]*b+Λ*Cosh[2*Sqrt[2*b^2-Λ^2]*z])
B[z_]:=(Sqrt[(2/a)*Sqrt[2]*(2*b^2-Λ^2)(Sqrt[2]*b-Λ)]*Sinh[Sqrt[2*b^2-Λ^2]*z])/(Sqrt[2]*b+Λ*Cosh[2*Sqrt[2*b^2-Λ^2]*z])

ψ1[z_,t_]:=A[z]*Exp[-I*Λ*t]
ψ2[z_,t_]:=I*B[z]*Exp[-I*Λ*t]

F1[z_,t_]:=(ψ1[z,t]+ψ2[z,t])/2;
F2[z_,t_]:=(ψ1[z,t]-ψ2[z,t])/2;
```

(It is known that `A[z]` and `B[z]` are real, `a` and `b` are positive reals, and `Λ` is real.)

I wish to simplify the following expressions in terms of the expressions defined above:

```
FullSimplify[Im[F1[z,t]*D[Conjugate[F2[z,t]],t]-
F1[z,t]*D[Conjugate[F2[z,t]],z]]]

FullSimplify[D[ψ1[z,t],t]+D[ψ2[z,t],z]+I*Sqrt[2]*b*ψ1[z,t]-I*(a/Sqrt[2])*ψ1[z,t]*(Abs[ψ1[z,t]^2-Abs[ψ2[z,t]^2]])]
```

(The second expression should probably simplify to zero.)

Unfortunately Mathematica takes forever to do this.

Is there a way to make this work? Also, are there any general tips with regard to manipulating complicated expressions in Mathematica?

Comment: F1[z,t], F2[z,t] aren't defined yet!

Comment: What is known about the several parameters?

Comment: Your expressions involve taking derivatives of `Conjugate`.  Mathematica has no built in model for this.  You need to reformulate to avoid this (perhaps you can interchange `D` and `Conjugate`)

Comment: @mikado, but the second expression does not have this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, it is known that $A[z]$ and $B[z]$ are real, $a$ and $b$ are positive reals, and $\Lambda$ is real. I added this information to the post. I also added the definition of $F1[z,t]$ and $F2[z,t]$. Thanks!

Comment: @mikado, when I change `D` and `Conjugate`, Mathematica gives a weird result after a long time. The result is 1/4 Re.

Comment: Are both `t` and `z` complex?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, `FullSimplify` does not achieve the simplifications one might hope.  Consider the second expression,

```
D[ψ1[z, t], t] + D[ψ2[z, t], z] + I*Sqrt[2]*b*ψ1[z, t] - I*(a/Sqrt[2])*ψ1[z, t]*
    (Abs[ψ1[z, t]^2] - Abs[ψ2[z, t]^2]);
```

where I have taken the liberty of rewriting the two `Abs` arguments so that they are not nested (as I assume that the OP intended).  Then, using `FullSimplify` with reasonable assumptions yields,

```
FullSimplify[%, a > 0 && b > 0 && 2 b^2 > Λ^2 && (Λ | t | z) ∈ Reals]

(* -(1/((Sqrt[2] b + Λ Cosh[2 z Sqrt[2 b^2 - Λ^2]])^2)) I 2^(1/4) E^(-I t Λ)
   Cosh[z Sqrt[2 b^2 - Λ^2]] (-2 (-Sqrt[2] b^2 Sqrt[((Sqrt[2] b + Λ) (2 b^2 - Λ^2))/a] + 
   b (-Λ Sqrt[((Sqrt[2] b + Λ) (2 b^2 - Λ^2))/a] + Sqrt[((Sqrt[2] b - Λ) 
   (-2 b^2 + Λ^2)^2)/a]) + Sqrt[2] Λ (Λ Sqrt[((Sqrt[2] b + Λ) (2 b^2 - Λ^2))/a] + 
   Sqrt[((Sqrt[2] b - Λ) (-2 b^2 + Λ^2)^2)/a])) + Λ ((-2 b + Sqrt[2] Λ) 
   Sqrt[((Sqrt[2] b + Λ) (2 b^2 - Λ^2))/a] + Sqrt[2] 
   Sqrt[((Sqrt[2] b - Λ) (-2 b^2 + Λ^2)^2)/a]) Cosh[2 z Sqrt[2 b^2 - Λ^2]]) *)
```

which appears to be the best that `FullSimplify` can do without handholding.  Yet, as suggested by the OP, inserting random numbers into this expression (with `2 b^2 > Λ^2`, as required) yields zero to roundoff.  Interestingly, `FullSimplify` has difficulty with even the simpler,

```
FullSimplify[(-(b - Λ) Sqrt[(b + Λ) (b^2 - Λ^2)] + Sqrt[(b - Λ) (b^2 - Λ^2)^2]) /. 
    b -> Sqrt[2] b, 2 b^2 > Λ^2 && b > 0]

(* Sqrt[Sqrt[2] b - Λ] (2 b^2 - Λ^2) + (-Sqrt[2] b + Λ) Sqrt[(Sqrt[2] b + Λ) 
   (2 b^2 - Λ^2)] *)
```

although not with the equivalent

```
FullSimplify[-(b - Λ) Sqrt[(b + Λ) (b^2 - Λ^2)] + Sqrt[(b - Λ) (b^2 - Λ^2)^2], 
    b^2 > Λ^2 && b > 0]
(* 0 *)
```